# MongoDB C# Query for 'NotLike' on string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using official Mongo C# driver. As suggested in answer to one question I'm using the following for the 'like' operator -

Query.Matches("name", "Joe");

My question is how can I achieve the 'NotLike' functionality ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the new Query builder in version 1.5, you would do it this way:

```
var query = Query.Not(Query.Matches("name", "Joe"));
```

In version 1.5 we also introduced a new typed Query builder, which you could use this way:

```
var query = Query.Not(Query<C>.Matches(x => x.Name, "Joe"));
```

Finally, you could also write a LINQ query:

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable<C>().Where(x => !Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, "Joe"));
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for always helping out so quickly